# Error reading bibtex file using pandoc with cite-proc "unexpected '\''

Tags: latex, pandoc, bibtex, csl, pandoc-citeproc

i have written an article wit Latex and want to submit it to the publisher. Unfortunately, they only accept .odt or .docx files. Therefore, i wanted to convert my file with pandoc, as i've done it multiple times with other documents.

I used a bash script which produces the following command:

```bash
pandoc -s --toc article.tex --citeproc --bibliography=my_bib_file.bib --csl=../../csl_citations_styles/dai.csl -o article.odt
```

But the process is stopped with the following error-message:

```
Error reading bibliography file my_bib_file.bib:
(line 1495, column 1):
unexpected '\''
```

I opened the bib-file and removed the `'`, but afterwards the error changed to:

```
Error reading bibliography file my-bib-file.bib:
(line 1496, column 1):
unexpected '@'
```

which absolutely makes no sense, because the `@` is the beginning of a bib-entry:

```
'
@Book{manzo_ancient_egypt_in_its_african_context,
  author     = {Manzo, Andrea},
  publisher  = {Cambridge University Press},
  title      = {Ancient Egypt in its African Context},
  year       = {2022},
}
```

I create the bib-file with JabRef. Thus, i don't look into the code very often. But i scanned the whole bib-file and an `'` in a line over a following bib-entry appears very often.

Pandoc complained about it in line 1495, but the `'` appears multiple times before.

Has anybody an idea

1. Why those `'` are appearing at all? (Couldnt find any answer for now).
2. Why Pandoc/cite-proc shows an error in the middle of my bib-file, whereas the `'` has already appeared multiple times.
3. **Most important**: How to solve this problem. I really dont want to create the bibliography and the references on my own in the .odt file. Its not the shortest article...

EDIT:

Okay, it seems to be a problem with one specific entry and not the `'`. I deleted the the entry and now it works. But couldn't find any error in the entry itself, so still a mysterium, but not due to the apostrophe's...

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad. The error occured, because an DOI of an entry i just imported using the Jabref-Firefox-Addon had special characters, which bibtex couldn't deal with...

Solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).